# How to make a loop with increment of time period in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

In my Oracle database there is a session table with user's login date and time. With this query I can get number of users who logged in (opened their session) within given time period - for example logged in January:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ses_username)
FROM
    sessions
WHERE
    to_char(ses_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59'
```

How to make a loop in PL/SQL that give me the count but by days per month or by hours per month or by hours per day or even quarter of an hour (15 minutes) by day.

EDIT:

Session table format is

```
ses_id  ses_start_date          ses_username
============================================
786895  2019-01-01 15:39:10     USER_1
786896  2019-01-01 15:39:11     USER_1
786897  2019-01-01 16:38:39     USER_1
786898  2019-01-01 16:38:40     USER_1
786899  2019-01-02 06:44:20     USER_2
786900  2019-01-02 06:44:21     USER_2
786901  2019-01-02 06:50:10     USER_3
786902  2019-01-02 06:50:11     USER_3
786903  2019-01-02 06:50:28     USER_4
786904  2019-01-02 06:50:30     USER_4
...
```

And I need to know how many unique usernames was logged in within every day in month or within every hour or within every 15 minutes per day.

Comment: please provide desired result and some sample data

Comment: I have edited the question for additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, what you mean by looping in your question. But Yes, If you want to see data day-wise then you can use the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` as following:

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(ses_start_date) AS SESSION_DAY,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ses_username)
FROM
    sessions
WHERE
   TRUNC(ses_start_date) BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2019-01-31'
   GROUP BY TRUNC(ses_start_date)
```

**Note:** Do not convert date to char and compare. Dates can be compared directly as shown in the example.

Cheers!!

Comment: It looks very interesting. With parameter 'format' the TRUNC function will truncate it to hours or minutes. If I think right... :-)

Comment: TRUNC truncates it to day.

Comment: TRUNC() can be used to truncate to other time components, such as mins:  select trunc( sysdate, 'MI' ) from dual

Comment: If there is no session on the day (no users have been logged in) then the date (line) is immited in the output. How to show dates with count 0? Nvl(count(), 0) doesn't work here.

Comment: To show dates not in the table you need to generate the list of dates then LEFT join sessions to that list. If you need Post another question.